# Can projectiles pass through enemies? How does the projectile penetration work?

Tags: tomb-raider-2013

- What weapons (and their upgrades, if it affects this) shoot projectiles that can pass through multiple enemies?
- How does the '[Penetrating Arrows](http://www.ign.com/wikis/tomb-raider/Penetrating_Arrows)' upgrade work?
- How many enemies can a projectile pass through?
- How does the damage work? Will the impact on the first enemy hit by the projectile, lessen damage to the second enemy hit?
- How does enemy armor affect the penetration and damage?

[image]

Comment: If you upgrade the bow with the penetrating arrow skill your arrows can penetrate armor and hit multiple enemies. Not sure how many enemies or the damage dropoff for this though.

Comment: To the downvoter(s): Could you please comment on why you downvoted this question? This is so I (and others) would know what was wrong with it, and so I could address that concern or edit the question to improve it. When downvotes are left without comments and the reasons for doing so are unclear, you'll often see users (like myself) wanting to know the reason why.

Comment: I completely agree. I think that is one of the biggest problems with this site. As for why this question is getting downvoted, I have no idea. I upvoted it because it seems like a very good question to me. I'm also interested in the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I got the penetrating arrows.  I haven't been able to use it agains soft issue enemies, but it seems they do not do any more damage to armored enemies than regular arrows do.